# JPA Query toString

Tags: java, google-app-engine, orm, jpa, datanucleus

I have a JPA Query I am executing on the Google App-Engine datastore.
I am building the query using parameters.
After all parameters have been inputted, I wish to view the Query String.

That is, I wish to view the actual query being executed by the datastore.
Is that even possible?
It would really help me in debugging.

To SOLVE the question, assume the following query:

```
Query query=EM.createQuery("SELECT FROM "
+MyClass.class.getName()+" C WHERE C.field = :arg1");
query.setParameter("arg1", someParam);
```

if `System.out.println(SomeObj)` prints 'SELECT FROM MyClass C WHERE C.field = 17'
then the question is solved.

David

Comment: Consider using `@NamedQueries`. They will be checked by your provider on startup, cached and are not vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @Willi As long as you use positional or named parameters in your queries, you're safe regarding SQL injection.

Comment: Right, but the above example uses string concatenation which could be avoided using named queries.

Comment: And since he is using GAE/J I don't see the relevance of SQL

Answer (score 1):

> That is, I wish to view the actual query being executed by the datastore.

Enabling `DEBUG` for the `DataNucleus.Datastore` log category should do it. Check  the [DataNucleus Logging](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/logging.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In current DataNucleus you can just call toString() on the JPA Query object to see the single-string form (without parameter substitution). The actual query invoked on the datastore depends on the datastore (obviously), being SQL in the case of RDBMS, and something else in the case of BigTable.